# MySql Workbench and SSL support

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

I want to connect to Amazon's RDS MySql service using MySql Workbench 5.2.33 running on Windows. I want to connect using SSL.

1. How do I do this?
2. How can I *verify* that I am connecting using SSL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open *Connect to database*. In the *Advanced* tab, enable "Use SSL if available", and point "SSL CA File" to the SSL root certificate of the MySQL server (in PEM format).

   The SSL CA setting is *required*.
2. Run the following query:

   ```
   show status like 'ssl_cipher';
   ```

   If the `Ssl_cipher` value is non-empty, the connection is secured using SSL.

   Alternatively, use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark.